# Method for "add to list" - Android application?? what method is suitable?

Tags: java, android, list, mobile

So i'm planning to develop an android application. In one activity, if i were to click a button of add, then it will prompt a user input and store the data. After that, thare would be another "list of item" button, where users can see which item they added and the information they input earlier.

I was thinking of using if.. else statement to check whether the button is click by setting a variable of default status=0 and change to 1 when clicked.

But how am i going to make sure that the functions won get messed up? is there any better suggestion for this? Im a beginner who just started to explore android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it is very simple and logical, and here is my best explanation. It's a rather long explanation, but I made it as thorough as possible...If you need any more help, just let me know:

---

You don't need to do any of that `status=0` stuff. Just have an onclick listener:

[image]
(androidfromhome.com)

And in the listener, you want to go to another screen with a text input. So, just have an intent in the onClick which takes user to another screen:

[image]
(www.devcfgc.com)

Okay, so now you got your second screen right? You're going to want a textview (Change this in the xml) in the middle of the screen, where the user can enter data:

```
String stuff = TextView.getText();
```

Note, you will need to initialize the textview:

[image]
(androidfromhome.com)

So, now you got the text that the user entered. Just save it in SharedPreferences, and that's it, you have it saved!

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Read about SharedPreferences in the link above.

So now, you have it saved. If you are going to get a lot of data, you can also save it in a database, which is more advanced stuff, that I don't know how to do. Now, display the saved data on the screen (A new screen, again, using an intent) using the method:

```
setText();
```

on your textView object for the next activity. That's it!

Comment: so i will have to add this to the every items in the first activity so that it can display all the items on the other activity?

Comment: @user3411128 You will add every item to the SharedPreferences/database that I talked about. If you are a beginner, I suggest you use SharedPreferences, but if you will have a lot of data, I suggest you use DataBase. You will have three activities, and I go into more detail about each one of those activities in my answer. Make sure to accept my answer (checkmark) if it is useful. Don't hesitate to ask me any more questions!

Comment: ok. i will try to do it like the way u said. thanks for helping

Comment: @user3411128 No problem!